# Making views custom field sortable in Drupal on a table view?

Tags: drupal-6, view

Custom field allows you to basically print any content in a field in a view. However, it is not sortable by default. Other than writing a view from scratch, what is the easiest way to allow for sorting using drupal views on a custom php field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Views' 'Relationship' together with 'Taxonomy: Term' to sort Custom Fields, full explanation below together with an instructional video.

http://drupal.org/node/272424#comment-1254224
http://drewish.com/node/127